# Selecting a set of rows more than once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a simple, concise way to select the same set of rows repeated based on a count held in a variable, without using a loop?

For instance, suppose `SELECT a, b, c FROM foo WHERE whatsit = something` returns

```
a   b   c
--- --- ----
1   2   3
```

...and I have `@count` with `3` in it. Is there a reasonable way without a loop to get:

```
a   b   c
--- --- ----
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
```

? Order doesn't matter, and I don't need to know which group any given row belongs to. I actually only need this for one row (as above), and a solution that only works for one row would do the trick, but I assume if we can do it for one, we can do it for any number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with a `Recursive CTE`

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1 AS id,a,b,c
         FROM   tablename
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id + 1,a,b,c
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  id < 3) --@count
SELECT a,b,c
FROM   cte
```

Comment: And of course, if the repeated `SELECT ... FROM tablename` bothers me, I can always throw another CTE on front to grab just the relevant row(s), then use those rows in the recursive one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - yes you can :)

Comment: How did we get by without CTEs? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do using  `cross join`

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT number
            FROM master.dbo.spt_values
            WHERE type = 'P'
            AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 3) T
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know of a way you could do this without a loop or dynamic SQL. I think a union is all that I can come up with

```
select q1.a,q1.b,q1.c
from (
    SELECT a, b, c FROM foo 
    union all
    SELECT a, b, c FROM foo 
    union all
    SELECT a, b, c FROM foo ) q1
order by q1.a
```

Comment: He has a `@count` variable. With your query you can't handle a change in the number of repetitions required.